# Can MIDI variable-length quantities be forced to a consistent four bytes?

Tags: midi

I am quite scatterbrained and I am suffering in writing a C program to compose MIDI files.

I'm currently planning to write two pseudo-MIDI files with C `long int` in the place of the variable-length delta times, then merge them and sort them at merging.

At that time I would convert non-delta times into delta times, and I'd be willing to put up with variable-length quantity format if someone would tell me: are these equivalent valid ways to encode decimal 1?

`00000001`

`10000000100000001000000000000001`

Clearly I am not impressed by any disk space reduction strategies.

Comment: I think this might be better suited for https://stackoverflow.com/ because your question is not really about any musical topic. Just because MIDI is used by musicians, doesn't make it on topic here.

Comment: Even for me, programming midi interfaces of devices from time to times, I don't understand clearly what is the question... Midi is an old and rigid format, you cannot add bits in the message and still having it working...

Comment: Short answer: **no**. You **must** use VLQ for delta-times. Why do you scared of VLQ? It's easy to read and write data in this format, and there are a lot of code snippets on the web showing how to do these conversions in all programming languages.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on stackoverflow. It is a pure programming question

Comment: Byte ordering is typically a property of the processor used. The assumption, that `long int` corresponds to 32 bit, is pretty vulnerable and depending additionally on the compiler. The C standard just specifies, that it is not shorter than int. For confirmation look into `limits.h`.